# How to set the value for variable in ARM template? Or Use of Or condition in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

I been working on ARM template and i want asign value to isAlwayOnEnable variable dynamically based on user selection of skuname.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
  "skuName": {
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 1,
    "allowedValues": [
      "D1","F1","B1","B2","B3","S1","S2","S3","P1","P2","3","P1V2","P2V2","P3V2","I1","I2","I3","Y1"
    ],
    "defaultValue": "F1",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
    }
  }
},
"variables": {
    "isAlwayOnEnable": "[if(equals(parameters('skuName'), or('P1','P2','P3','P1V2','P2V2','P3V2','S1','S2','S3')), 'true', 'false')]"
    },
"resources": []
}
```

But it has an issue while validating the arm template.

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression 'if(equals(parameters('skuName'), or('P1','P2','P3','P1V2','P2V2','P3V2','S1','S2','S3')), true, false)': expected token 'LeftParenthesis' and actual 'Comma'.'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.","additionalInfo":[{"type":"TemplateViolation","info":{"lineNumber":0,"linePosition":0,"path":""}}]}}
```

Can anyone point me where i am doing the mistake ?

I also tried to use this variable like

```
"isAlwayOnEnable": "[or(if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'S1') ,'true','false'), if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'S2') ,'true','false'),if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'S3') ,'true','false'),  if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'P1') ,'true','false'),if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'P2') ,'true','false'),if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'P3') ,'true','false'),if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'P1V2') ,'true','false'),if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'P2V2') ,'true','false'),if(equals(parameters('skuName'),'P3V2') ,'true','false'))]"
```

then i got below error

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'isAlwayOnEnable' is not valid: The provided arguments for template language function 'or' is not valid: all arguments should be of type 'boolean'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions#or for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.","additionalInfo":[{"type":"TemplateViolation","info":{"lineNumber":136,"linePosition":534,"path":"properties.template.variables.isAlwayOnEnable"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable section -

```
"variables": {
    "isAlwayOnEnable": "[if(equals(parameters('skuName'), 'P1'), 'true','false')]"
},
```

evaluates true when `skuName` as `P1` is selected else false.
So you can just add more condition with 'OR' operators and that should work.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical#if

**[EDIT 1 ]**

Using 'OR' conditions for multiple values-

```
"variables": {
    "isAlwayOnEnable": "[or (equals(parameters('skuName'), 'P1'), equals(parameters('skuName'), 'P2'))]"
},
```

Now I believe you can just put more `equals(parameters('skuName'), 'VALUE'))` after putting a comma based on your need.

I have tested below one ARM Template and this works as  expected-

```
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "skuName": {
            "defaultValue": "F1",
            "allowedValues": [
                "D1",
                "F1",
                "B1",
                "B2",
                "B3",
                "S1",
                "S2",
                "S3",
                "P1",
                "P2",
                "3",
                "P1V2",
                "P2V2",
                "P3V2",
                "I1",
                "I2",
                "I3",
                "Y1"
            ],
            "minLength": 1,
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier for the hosting plan."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "isAlwayOnEnable": "[or (equals(parameters('skuName'), 'P1'), equals(parameters('skuName'), 'P2'))]"
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "Result": {
            "type": "bool",
            "value": "[variables('isAlwayOnEnable')]"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

which is expected as per the logic. And also -

[image]
[image]

Try it out yourself at https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template before marking this question as helpful/not helpful.

Comment: Tell me how to add that ? :)

Comment: @PramodLawate EDIT 1 is for you

Comment: Thank you for your help, It resolve with this change.